# ExprTk with increased precision

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, exprtk

I am trying to compile the ExprTk library with more precision than `long double`. I thought the simplist would be to try GCC's `__float128` but I am getting the following compilation error and am not sure how to correct it.

```
exprtk.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static T exprtk::details::and_op<T>::process(exprtk::details::and_op<T>::Type, exprtk::details::and_op<T>::Type) [with T = __float128; exprtk::details::and_op<T>::Type = const __float128&]’:
exprtk.hpp:28439:10:   required from ‘void exprtk::parser<T>::load_binary_operations_map(exprtk::parser<T>::binary_op_map_t&) [with T = __float128; exprtk::parser<T>::binary_op_map_t = std::map<exprtk::details::operator_type, __float128 (*)(const __float128&, const __float128&), std::less<exprtk::details::operator_type>, std::allocator<std::pair<const exprtk::details::operator_type, __float128 (*)(const __float128&, const __float128&)> > >; typename exprtk::details::functor_t<T>::bfunc_t = __float128 (*)(const __float128&, const __float128&)]’
exprtk.hpp:15660:51:   required from ‘exprtk::parser<T>::parser(std::size_t) [with T = __float128; std::size_t = long unsigned int]’
mathtof.cpp:18:33:   required from here
exprtk.hpp:9923:105: error: call of overloaded ‘is_true(const __float128&)’ is ambiguous
          static inline T process(Type t1, Type t2) { return (details::is_true(t1) && details::is_true(t2)) ? T(1) : T(0); }
                                                                                                         ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

EDIT:

I've tried implementing my own `is_true`

```
<typename T>
inline bool is_true(const T v)
{
    return std::not_equal_to<T>()(T(0),v);
}
```

Comment: `is_true` vs `is_true_impl`?  Also, based on the error, you need to put it inside the `details` namespace.  `is_true` is called using a qualified name, so ADL won't trigger.

Comment: My mistake, it was `is_true`. I made it by copying that `is_true_impl` directly inline with the other definitions of `is_true` and `is_ture_impl`.

Comment: Did your attempt to define `is_true` account for the namespace?

Comment: Yes, it was directly above their implementation inside the `detail` namespace.

Comment: It looks like this effort is likely worthless because all math is done by casting to `double`.

Comment: I see a lot of casts to `double` associate with `int_type_tag`, none for `real_type_tag`.  But then, I only took a quick look.

Comment: @BenVoigt What I saw that made me think it was the `exp` routine calls `std::exp`

Comment: Note that adding a template definition make ambiguity worse.  Add a special overload for exactly `__float128`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is rather trivial to specialize ExprTk upon a custom numeric type. There are TWO examples found on the project's page that give a clear and concise means to introduce new numeric types within ExprTk.

The examples are:

1. Custom Real Type Adaptor [[link]](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7b1099ee2f9c2b52cb67)
2. MPFR Adaptor [[link]](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7072e9bf174cb5fe2e59)

The real type example implements a simple *real type* using the double type. Furthermore it provides the necessary additions into the ExprTk namespace that needs to be included prior to including the actual ExprTk header.

The MPFR adaptor builds upon the previous example and shows how one can easily adapt the MPFR/GMP type for use in ExprTk.

Both examples come packaged with the full test suite and benchmark using the newly introduced types.

---

Here is an example where someone has adapted their own type called **DScalar** to ExprTk:

https://github.com/filiatra/gismo/blob/stable/external/exprtk_ad_adaptor.hpp

and here it is being used:

https://github.com/filiatra/gismo/blob/stable/src/gsCore/gsFunctionExpr.hpp#L146

---

It should be noted that one can simply take the ***"Custom Real Type Adaptor"*** and search-n-replace the string "real::type" with ***__float128*** and some other minor replace changes and should be all good to go.

Comment: My jar literally dropped. I promised I looked there before asking here.

Comment: The provided adapter example doesn't actually compile for me. I haven't tried the MPFR one yet.

Comment: @chewsocks redownload both again, there may have been an issue with printf - also make sure you copy exprtk.hpp to where its needed as both packages don't include the header as part of the download.

Comment: Thanks for the update! It compiles and runs now. I would never have guessed printf was the cause of the errors I saw.

Answer (score 1):

It obviously doesn't support `__float128` (gcc itself barely supports it, you need the Boost `float128.h` library to do anything remotely useful with it).

You can try to provide the missing `is_true(__float128&)` overload, it should be relatively trivial, but I'm willing to bet money that won't be the end of it.

Comment: Note that my knowledge of gcc's support for `__float128` is a few years old, maybe more recent versions got better -- though I doubt it. There isn't much of a market for software emulated floating point operations when you can do billions at once on your garden variety GPU :)

Comment: Okay, so I changed it to using `boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100` because I figured it would have a more complete set of overloads. Nope, same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about doing floating point calcs on a GPU. The benefit of a software implementation is high precision. Up until recently a GPU could only do 32-bit floats.

Comment: I tried adding my own `is_true` and still no go. (see edit)

Comment: I copied the existing implementation and pasted above it.